# How to give type annotation for empty set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-typing, python-typing

I have this line in python;

```
set1 = set()  # create empty set
```

When I use mypi to scan, I get the error `Need type annotation for 'set1'`

How do I give type annotation for empty set?

I am using python 3.7 and mypi plugin in pycharm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simple version: `set1: set = set()`

More specific version:

```
from typing import Set
set1: Set[<type>] = set()
```

e.g. for set of strings: `set1: Set[str] = set()`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is *requiring* a type annotation, but that annotation would simply be

```
set1: set = set()
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the previous answers are incorrect. An annotation of `set` is exactly the same as `set[Any]`, which means any set would be valid.

The correct answer is that there is no way to type an empty set. The best recommendation currently is to use `set[object]`, which atleast will result in a type error for most operations if someone tries to use values from it. See some discussion, for example, at https://github.com/python/typing/issues/157

There are some incidental methods that can be used to type certain other empty types though, such as:

```
EmptyString = Literal[""]
EmptyTuple = tuple[()]

class EmptyDict(TypedDict):
    """Empty dict for typing."""
```